# Using checkbox in each listview item row, need to show selected item(s) name into another activity

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using `checkbox`es in each `listview` item row, now I need to show selected `item(s)` name into another activity,here I am fetching data using a JSON parser.

I don't know how to get selected `listview` item name to another activity, I am using a submit button once the user has finished with `checkbox` selection, he/she just needs to click on submit and need to show selected item names into another activity.  I know how to use the intent to send data to another activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for a solution like I do before. Read [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive) Tutorial, it will help ypu :-)